# мне нужно загрузить фото с разрешением jpeg в андроид эмулятор, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать

Tags: python, adb, appium

Я новичёк в Appium, нашёл в документации этот код для python

```
dest_path = '/data/local/tmp/test_push_file.txt'
data = bytes('This is the contents of the file to push to the device.', 'utf-8')
self.driver.push_file(dest_path, base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf-8'))
```

но при применении выдаёт ошибку "Appium error: failed to copy 'C:\Users...' remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system"

Comment: Вам нужно показать пример кода.